# What is difference between partial indexes and sparse indexes mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've read official docs of MongoDB but really can't understand the difference between sparse and partial indexes. I wanted to have an explanatory view with examples.

Comment: it's explained here : [comparison-with-the-sparse-index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/#comparison-with-the-sparse-index)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Sparse index is an optimized index which only contains pointers to documents that have value(s) in the indexed fields.
For example, let's say you would like to add an index on lastname field

```
{ _id: 1, firstname: 'John', lastname: 'Black', age: 20 }
{ _id: 2, firstname: 'Stive', lastname: 'White', age: 17 }
{ _id: 3, firstname: 'Tom', age: 22 }
```

if you run

```
db.users.createIndex({ lastname: 1 });
```

command, it will add indexes on 3 documents, but you don't need to have an index on a document where is no lastname value (_id: 3); it's a waste of space and memory.
To avoid empty fields' indexing, mongodb has `sparse` index, which is simply "check for non-empty value".
So when you add `sparse: true`

```
db.users.createIndex({ lastname: 1, sparse: true });
```

Mongodb will add indexes only for 2 documents (_id: 1, _id:2). Its great, but what if you want to index only those users' documents which are older than 18 years?
You cant use sparse index because it only checks documents for value existence.

This is why `partial indexes` were created.

```
db.person.createIndex( 
  { age: 1}, 
  { partialFilterExpression: { age: { $gte: 18 }, lastname: { $exists: true }}
);
```

This example will put index only for 1 document(id: 1). Partial index is complex version of sparse, it will filter documents not only checking their existence, but using conditions provided in `partialFilterExpression` field.

Comment: a very good solution and in fact a very clean and simple solution I was looking for. Thanks !!!. If you found this question useful/interesting please mark it up or favorite.

Comment: Great concise explanation! Thanks!

Comment: Just for completeness sake, if you wanted to implement that `{lastname:1, sparse:true}` index as a partial index instead, it would be: `{ { lastname: 1}, partialFilterExpression: { lastname: { $exists: true }}}`

Comment: Should not be documents stored in index sparse by default? What is the point of having a document, that does not have the field you index? You cannot lookup that document anyway, so why to have it in index?